# MySQL ERROR 1005 (HY000) : Can't create table

Tags: mysql

Table

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name          | varchar(64) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table2

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 
    ADD COLUMN person_id int(11), 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_person_id(person_id) references Table(id);
```

This gives me an error,

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'table2.#sql-3fb_7cf' (errno: 150)

The primary key for table 1 `id` is proper. Where else is it failing?

Comment: Is your table actually named 'Table' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When altering table and add a foreign key, you must add the referencing column as a key before you add it as a foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 
    ADD COLUMN person_id int(11),
    ADD INDEX(person_id),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_person_id(person_id) references Table(id);
```

Comment: +1 In fact it is *required*; any foreign key *must* be indexed.

Comment: No problem.. Don't we all wish MySQL gives more useful error messages?